# Typescript & Googleapis Surge in Memory Used

Tags: node.js, typescript, google-sheets-api

We've been tracking for a while an Out of Memory error that seemed to happen from time to time in the build step.
We finally pinpointed the commit. Said commit caused the `tsc --alwaysStrict` build to go from 175MB (RAM) to complete the build to 656MB.

That commit only added the `googleapis` library to the `package.json` and use it like so `import { google } from "googleapis";`. Those two changes alone created this spike.

Another thing that we saw is that the inclusion of the library on the `package.json` incremented the build by 100MB, however, once we add the `import` it goes all the way up to 600MB.
It is important to say that we are only interested in gSheets.

I see a couple options going forward but I do not like any of those:

1. Increasing the RAM of the server (currently 1GB)
2. Using a custom or non-oficial library for this purpose

Is there another way to solve this?

Answer (score 6):

I encountered the same issue, though for me the problem surfaced when running jest unit-tests, even the simplest test would consume up to 1GB of memory and cause our CI machine to crash.

seems like some progress was made and you can now import specific modules from @googleapis

look at: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/2187

for example:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@googleapis/drive
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@googleapis/calendar

haven't tried it yet, but I hope it will solve the issue.

EDIT:
tried using the service-specific packages i mentioned above, and it worked like a charm. give it a try

Comment: Thank you. It indeed worked like a charm!  node memory consumption was reduced from 1GB to 250MB.